# MongoDB Replica Set status from PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Is there a way to get the output of "rs.status();" from the php driver?

Passing the following setting to the Command function of the MongoDB Driver

```
array('replSetGetStatus'=>1)
```

Results in an error message:

```
Array
(
[0] => access denied; use admin db
[1] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reuse the same connection; you just have to get the admin db from the object:

```
$connection->admin->command(array("replSetGetStatus"=>1)
```

If you haven't already, you'll need to create a database connection object to the 'admin' db so that you can then call the output of rs.status() through the driver as you specified.

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2:],...]/db
```

See the docs [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.construct.php)